# Formato de fecha incorrecto al utilizar DatePicker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Tengo un campo DateTime con su BootstrapDatePicker como el siguiente:

```
 <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePicker, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DatePicker)                  
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
         </div>
```

Y su respectivo Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //DatePicker
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                minDate: new Date(),
                locale: 'es'
            });
```

Modelo:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Formato incorrecto")]
        public DateTime? DatePicker { get; set; }
```

El problema es al enviar la fecha. me acepta valores desde `03/1/2018`  al `03/12/2018` funciona correctamente, pero si mando `03/13/2018` la página solamente me devuelve un BadRequest. El formato de mi fecha está en formato inglés. No entiendo porque está fallando al momento de enviarle del valor 13 en adelante. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Si pruebas `dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy"` en el js??

Comment: No funciona, la version de bootstrap picker es la siguiente [BootstrapPicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) @LuisFernando

Comment: Tu servidor esta esperando la fecha en español al aprecer, lo que yo hago es recibir las fechas como texto y parsear en el server, si no es un rollo, saludos

Comment: Prueba invirtiendo estas lineas `defaultDate: new Date(),
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',` por `format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', defaultDate: new Date(),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes manejar formatos a tu gusto en tus fechas tanto del lado del backend como de frontend. Pero al momento de trabajar el la fecha como tal, lo más recomendable es que conserves su tipo de Datetime. Con datepicker utiliza su función de [getDate](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/2dVGIJ).

```
let fecha = $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker("getDate");
```

Si aún de utilizar esta función persiste las fechas cambiadas entonces aplica [.toISOString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) a tu Datetime; inclusive puedes llamarlo en la misma linea

```
let fecha = $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker("getDate").toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto los formatos son distintos, en el ordenamiento del picker `format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',` y de tu modelo `DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}"` como ves en el picker le das un ordenamiento `mes/día/año` y en el modelo `día/mes/año` este es el problema, ya que, deben ser iguales. Sí lo que estas haciendo es destinado para personas de latino américa te recomiendo que sólo cambies el picker por `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',` . Con ello ya no debería haber problemas.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no lo realizas de ésta forma mucho más fácil?

HTML

```
        <input type="text" id="TXTFecha" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 81.39%" class="form-control" />
```

Jquery

```
    $(function () {

    $("#TXTFecha").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',//Puedes poner el formato que deseas(dd.mmm.yy | mm/dd/yy | dd-mm-yy ETC)
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            finicio = dateText; //Ésta variable la puedes enviar a tu controlador siempre con el valor actual.
        }
    });

    });
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.